# I get errors when viewing forms in the designer - how can i avoid this?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows-forms-designer

Some of my forms show errors when i load them in the designer. This is because in their constructors they use system settings loaded from a configuration file. When the form is loaded in the designer it uses some random path and unsurprisingly the config file isn't there.

eg. 
The configuration file C:\Documents and Settings\Rory\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\VisualStudio\8.0\ProjectAssemblies\it3dtcgg01\PrioryShared.dll.config could not be found.

Is there some way I can deal with this so that the form displays correctly in the designer? 
eg:

```
if (!inDesignerMode) 
{ 
    loadSettingsFromConfigFile();
}
```

UPDATE: 
ok, I'm still getting this error. The composition is like this

- MyForm.cs

  - MyCustomControl.cs

In MyCustomControl's constructor I've put

```
if (!this.DesignMode)
{
    // Get settings from config file   <- this is where the error occurs
}
```

but it's on that line that I still get the error in the designer. What gives?

UPDATE: Worth noting [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996457.aspx#) that describes how to debug design-time controls.

UPDATE: Control.DesignMode isn't set to true when called within the constructor ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996457.aspx)) of the object! So that sort of code should go in the onLoad. Alternatively you can use an approach like [this](http://devlicious.com/blogs/derik_whittaker/archive/2006/09/25/Determining-if-the-.Net-IDE-is-in-Design-Mode.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about simply putting that logic into `OnLoad` instead, and check `DesignMode`?

```
protected override void OnLoad(System.EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);
    if (!this.DesignMode)
    {
        /* do stuff */
    }        
}
```

Comment: The line of code inside (!this.DesignMode) is still being executed at design mode - how can that be?

Comment: NB: the critical point here is to put the code into OnLoad instead of in the Constructor.

Answer (score 2):

You should wrap the items in a check on `this.DesignMode`, which is set to `true` when in the designer, or move them to `OnLoad` or some other place that doesn't get called during designer use.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can do something like this:

```
public bool IsDesignMode
{
   get
      {
         return (System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName == "devenv");
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Page.DesignMode
```

This can be used in all pages and user controls.

Comment: Page? The tags suggest this is winforms

Comment: I believe Page is a WPF or Silverlight concept.

Comment: You misunderstood, when I say "Page" i mean System.Web.UI.Page, which derives from Control.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do when I have to do some special handling if the control is currently used by the designer.

```
public MyControl() {
  InitializeComponent();
  if (LicenseManager.UsageMode != LicenseUsageMode.Designtime)  {
    // Put stuff here that should not be run while in the designer
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've always found it to be a mistake for a control to use a configuration file. Instead, the control should have settable properties, and if the form using it wants to set those properties from configuration, then it's welcome to do so.